# ElasticSearch - How can I get all of a document's fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to investigate an ElasticSearch index for which I have no documentation. Some of the documents in this index have parent-child relationships. So I issued:

```
 curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
    {
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "type": "entity",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "_id": "PROFILE_19986956"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And got:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : 13,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "myindex",
      "_type" : "property",
      "_id" : "PROFILE_19986956_name",
      "_score" : 1.0
    }, 
    ...
    ]
  }
```

Now I want to get the value of the document with ID `PROFILE_19986956_name` so I do `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/property/PROFILE_19986956_name?routing=0&pretty'` and get:

`{
  "_index" : "myindex",
  "_type" : "property",
  "_id" : "PROFILE_19986956_name",
  "_version" : 3,
  "found" : true
}`

Which has no value for the name, which I was expecting to get. I know it has to be there because searching for the entity's name yields a result but for some reason I can't get the field that contains the name. How can I get ES to show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the mapping, I think the fields are indexed but the source is disabled. Try :

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex
```

and see if the mapping has :

```
"_source": {
    "enabled": false
  }
```

If you see this, the source of the documents has not been indexed in elasticsearch, so you can't get it from it.

Comment: Source is indeed disabled. So you mean the value can be searched for but not viewed? If so, then how was I able to find that entity by name?

Comment: Elasticsearch has analyzed the fields and filled its index with the result, but has not kept the initial value.Though not recommended by elasticsearch (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/mapping-source-field.html#_disabling_the_literal__source_literal_field), if the entity is already store in a database and Elasticsearch is juste here to provide a search solution, it is perfectly acceptable.
Your entity must be stored in another database, and Elastisearch is populated from this database.